Chocolatey-UninstallPackage crashes with error illegal characters in path
I am trying to package a program with an InstallShield installer. The installer is a .exe file. Unfortunately, I am writing my own chocolateyUninstall.ps1, as Chocolatey's auto-uninstaller is failing to detect and uninstall the program by itself. To this end I am trying to use the Uninstall-ChocolateyPackage cmdlet like this:
$ErrorActionPreference = 'Stop'

$packageArgs = @{
  packageName    = $env:ChocolateyPackageName
  softwareName   = 'TRACE32*'
  fileType       = 'EXE'
  silentArgs     = '/s'
  validExitCodes = @(0)
}

[array]$key = Get-UninstallRegistryKey -SoftwareName $packageArgs['softwareName']
if ($key.Count -eq 1) {
  $key | % {
    $packageArgs['file'] = "$($_.UninstallString)".Trim()
    Uninstall-ChocolateyPackage @packageArgs
  }
}

When calling Uninstall-ChocolateyPackage the packageArgs hashmap contains the following values:
$packageArgs['packageName'] = trace32
SpackageArgs['softwareName'] = TRACE32*
$packageArgs['file'] = "C:\Program Files (x86)\InstallShield Installation Information\{A31FFDB6-5922-4D9E-ADB1-285E5D999D70}\setup.exe" -runfromtemp -l0x0409  -removeonly
$packageArgs['fileType'] = EXE
$packageArgs['silentArgs'] = /s

But at this point chocolateyUninstall.ps1 crashes stating that there are "illegal characters in the path" ... However, when I copy the contents of $packageArgs['file'] to an elevated command line (CMD or PowerShell), paste it and run it the uninstallation of the program proceeds normally and successfully.
I could not find any report of such an issue with Google. Has anyone ever encountered a problem like this? And, if yes, what was the root cause and how did you solve it? I would like for Chocolatey-UninstallPackage to call the uninstallation command registered in the Windows Registry properly and finish successfully.
I am still using Chocolatey 1.3.1 if that is relevant.
Thanks in advance for your input!

Can I suggest popping the log or output from when "chocolateyUninstall.ps1 crashes" in here? I'm surprised that you're having an issue, as far as I'm aware there are other InstallShield packages uninstalling fine.

There was really not much more than what I described above in chocolatey.log

Just to be clear, nothing is 'crashing'. An exception is being thrown, which is what is intended to happen.
The problem you have is that your hashtable is wrong. The $packageArgs['file'] doesn't contain a filename. It contains a filename AND args. You need to split that up into the filename, and the args left need to go into $packageArgs['silentArgs'] like this:
$packageArgs['packageName'] = trace32
SpackageArgs['softwareName'] = TRACE32*
$packageArgs['file'] = "C:\Program Files (x86)\InstallShield Installation Information\{A31FFDB6-5922-4D9E-ADB1-285E5D999D70}\setup.exe"
$packageArgs['fileType'] = EXE
$packageArgs['silentArgs'] = "-runfromtemp -l0x0409  -removeonly"

Note that I'm assuming those $packageArgs['silentArgs'] do actually uninstall it silently.

I am still using Chocolatey 1.3.1 if that is relevant.

That is an old and unsupported version of Chocolatey CLI that was released over a year ago.

I think this is the answer. Looking at the registry keys under HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall{...}) I notice that the UninstallString tend to contain arguments. I think standard Chocolatey PowerShell snippets fail to uninstall this particular program because they do not split the UninstallString into the file and silentArgs fields ...

They do. There are sorts of good stuff stored in that registry key, so asking the Chocolatey PowerShell functions to make sense of it automatically wouldn't be a good idea.
